# query for male to female ratio in the given dataset #MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sum, pivot, average

how to write query for male to female ratio of the given dataset

```
select gender
     , sum( case when gender = 'male'
                 then 1 else 0 end )    as male
     , sum( case when gender = 'female'
                 then 1 else 0 end )    as female
  from adult;
```

this gives separate count but no ratio.

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Since we can't see the actual dataset it's quite tricky to write code to process or query it, don't you think? We can make guesses about what's likely based on what you've written so far, bit it's much easier to be certain if we can see a data sample and your expected output based on the sample

Comment: remove gender from your select. select only the sum

Comment: *"how to write query for male to female ratio of the given dataset"* Why does this sounds like a homework or job interview related question? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT()` in combination with `IF()` to get the counts and ratio of the gender.

Example table content:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | gender |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | John  | male   |
|  2 | Jane  | female |
|  3 | Stacy | female |
|  4 | Karen | female |
|  5 | Bob   | male   |
+----+-------+--------+
```

With the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF(gender = 'male', 1, NULL)) count_male,
    COUNT(IF(gender = 'female', 1, NULL)) count_female,
    COUNT(IF(gender = 'male', 1, NULL))/COUNT(IF(gender = 'female', 1, NULL)) as ratio
FROM
    users;
```

you will get the following result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| count_male | count_female | ratio  |
+------------+--------------+--------+
|          2 |            3 | 0.6667 |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are only two possible genders, this query can give you the ratio of males within the total population, on a 0 to 1 scale:

```
select avg(gender = 'male') ration from adult;
```

And here is the ratio of females:

```
select avg(gender = 'female') ration from adult;
```

If you are looking for the ratio of females to males, then:

```
select sum(gender = 'female') / nullif(sum(gender = 'male'), 0) from adult;
```